# x-editable multiple submit buttons - different url or parameters

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, x-editable

I have a page with the below code.
What I'm trying to achieve is x-editable form with two submit buttons, which should either call two different url or call the same url but with different parameters.

This is the html code

```
<table width="100%" height="100%" border="1">
    <tr>
        <td>Name</td>
        <td>First name</td>
        <td>Position</td>
        <td>Company</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td class="editable" id="required" data-pk='1' data-name="name1">Name 1</td>
        <td class="editable" id="required" data-pk='2' data-name="name2">Firstname 1</td>
        <td class="editable" id="required" data-pk='3' data-name="name3">Position 1</td>
        <td class="editable" id="required" data-pk='4' data-name="name4">Company 1</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td class="editable" id="required" data-pk='5' data-name="name5">Name 2</td>
        <td class="editable" id="required" data-pk='6' data-name="name6">Firstname 2</td>
        <td class="editable" id="required" data-pk='7' data-name="name7">Position 2</td>
        <td class="editable" id="required" data-pk='8' data-name="name8">Company 2</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td class="editable" id="required" data-pk='9' data-name="name9">Name 3</td>
        <td class="editable" id="required" data-pk='10' data-name="name10">Firstname 3</td>
        <td class="editable" id="required" data-pk='11' data-name="name11">Position 3</td>
        <td class="editable" id="required" data-pk='12' data-name="name12">Company 3</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

This is javascript

```
$.fn.editable.defaults.mode = 'popup';
$.fn.editable.defaults.title = 'Edit';
$.fn.editable.defaults.type = 'text';
$.fn.editable.defaults.toggle = 'dblclick';

$.fn.editableform.buttons  = 
    '<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm editable-submit"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></i></button>'+
    '<button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm editable-cancel"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></i></button>'+
    '<button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm editable-off"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i></button>';

$('.editable').editable({
    validate: function(value) {
        if($.trim(value) == '') {
            return 'Value is required.';
        }
    },
    url: 'save.php',
    send: 'always'
});

$(document).on('click','.editable-submit',function() {
    $('.editable-open').editable('submit', {
        url: 'save.php',
        params: function (params) {
            var data = {};
            data['value'] = params.value;           
            data['pk'] = params.pk;
            data['originalValue'] = $(this).text();
            data['action'] = 'edit';
            return data;
        },
        success: function(params, config) {
            console.log(params);
        }
    });
});

$(document).on('click','.editable-off',function() {
    $('.editable-open').editable('submit', {
        url: 'save2.php',
        params: function (params) {
            var data = {};
            data['value'] = params.value;           
            data['pk'] = params.pk;
            data['originalValue'] = $(this).text();
            data['action'] = 'exclude';
            return data;
        },
        success: function(params, config) {
            console.log(params);
        }
    });
});
```

The problem is that at present moment both buttons submit same parameters to same url, the one defined at the editable fire line.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try out this:

```
function SubscribeSendButton(url, btnClass){
  $(document).on('click',btnClass,function(){
    $('.editable-open').editable('submit', {
      ajaxOptions: { url: url },
      params: function (params) {
                  var data = {};
                  data['value'] = params.value;           
                  data['pk'] = params.pk;
                  data['originalValue'] = $(this).text();
                  data['action'] = 'exclude';
                  return data;
              },
      success: function(params, config) {
          console.log(params);
      }
    });
  });
};

SubscribeSendButton('save1.php','.editable-off');
SubscribeSendButton('save2.php','.editable-submit');
```

**[update 1]**

you should use

```
ajaxOptions: { url: url },
```

instead of just

```
 { url: url }
```

my working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rb1bxefv/
and your's with ajax emulation: http://jsfiddle.net/qbeuanuf/5/

Comment: Thanks for your swift reply. Tried it. `editable` doesn't fire. And if i load `$('.editable').editable();` it seems that without configuring `url` the `editable` doesn't fire. And if I configure `url` it remains unchanged even though running through the function you built. Thanks again!

Comment: @Catalin, could you provide some fiddle, so I might play with it online?

Comment: thanks for your time. fiddle link `http://jsfiddle.net/qbeuanuf/2/`. Sorry, I'm not really god at posting, I'm doing this for the first time. Thank you in advance!

Comment: I didn't figure that I should change settings via `ajaxOptions`. It works like a charm. Own you a beer, mate! Thanks.